# Oracle - display all within next 12 months

Tags: oracle

I am trying to pull all data within the next 12 months only. the only thing i can find online is "addmonths" but can't get it, not sure if it's because the date in the Start_date column is DD/MM/YYYY?

```
select number, start_date from wo_table
where start_date between sysdate and addmonths(sysdate,12)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show us the definition of your `wo_table`?

Comment: Please be careful with `number` as this is one of Oracle [reserved words](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "number", start_date
FROM   wo_table
WHERE  start_date BETWEEN SYSDATE
                      AND ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, 12 );
```

Or

```
SELECT "number", start_date
FROM   wo_table
WHERE  start_date BETWEEN SYSDATE
                      AND SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' YEAR;
```

Answer (score -1):

figured it out for future reference incase it helps others:

```
select number, start_date from wo_table
```

`where start_date between sysdate and sysdate+365`

simple :)